# Calling a function with a Generic parameter requires a no-arg init for the type

Tags: swift, combine

I'm having trouble getting a function call using a generic type to work using a `URLSession` `DataTaskPublisher`...

The API I'm calling always responds with an HTTP 200, and indicates whether it was successful or not in the JSON via a `code` string with an indicator.

I created a `protocol` that all response objects conform to, e.g.:

```
protocol APIResponse: Decodable {
    var code: String { get }
}
```

My actual response will be something like:

```
struct LoginResponse :  APIResponse {
    let code: String
    let name: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "code"
        case name = "name"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        code = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .code)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

Now I want a function like this that I can use:

```
    private func call<T: APIResponse>(_ endpoint: String, using data: Encodable, providing response: T)
                    -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
        let request = createRequest(for: endpoint, using: data)
        return session
                .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
                .map {
                    $0.data
                }
                .decode(type: T.self, decoder: decoder)
                .tryMap {
                    response in
                    if response.code.suffix(1) != "I" {
                        throw MyError(message: "Error \(code)")
                    }
                    return response
                }
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

So far, so good!

But here's the problem... I want to use it like this:

```
    func login() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
        call("login", using: LoginRequest(), providing: LoginResponse)
                .map {
                    $0.name
                }
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

The compiler complains with `Type 'LoginResponse.Type' cannot conform to 'APIResponse'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`

My fix (which works, but is kludgy), it to provide a no-arg `init()` for `LoginResponse` and call it like this: `call("login", using: LoginRequest(), providing: LoginResponse())`

Any way to get the Generic to work without the no-arg `init()`?

Should I be taking a totally different approach?

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't actually need to manually implement `init(from: )` or define `CodingKeys` - Swift will auto-synthesize conformance on its own

Comment: True, this was cut down from a much larger API response that did some object name translation, I should have removed from my snippet. Good point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to pass the response type to this function:

```
private func call<T: APIResponse>(_ endpoint: String,
                                  using data: Encodable) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
        // no change here
}
```

But you might have to help the compiler here by specifying the type of the closure used in map as it has no way of guessing which type is returned from this generic function:

```
func login() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
    call("login", using: LoginRequest())
            .map { (response: LoginResponse) -> String in
                response.name
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

You can also simplify your LoginResponse:

```
struct LoginResponse: APIResponse {
    let code: String
    let name: String
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I actually started with something similar to this before going the route of the `providing:` parameter, but missed the type specification in the closure.

Answer (score 3):

In the header for `call` change `response` parameter to

```
...providing response: T.Type)
```

and call it using `.self`

```
call("login", using: "request", providing: LoginResponse.self)
```

Comment: Ah, that was the missing bit of syntax... thank you! Your suggestion definitely works. Per @LuLuGaGa above though, this can be done slightly cleaner without the extra parameter at all.

Comment: @Devin, the other approach is, IMHO, actually less clean, since it requires specifying the type at random places, as opposed to explicitly in the function. This approach aligns with what `JSONDecoder.decode` is doing. You can actually handle both if you provide a default parameter value, when its otherwise inferred with `providing response: T.Type = T.self)`

Comment: Hmm... interesting... the "messy"ness in my opinion was the unused parameter, but I guess it's no better to have a random type specification later on...

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, the cleanest approach, in my view, is to create an `Endpoint` protocol that knows about its own response, so as to remove this redundancy from the `call` function.

It would look something like this:

```
protocol Endpoint {
   associatedtype Response: Decodable
   var request: URLRequest { get }
}

func call<E: Endpoint>(endpoint: E) -> AnyPublisher<E.Response, Error> {
   //...
}
```

define the endpoint like this:

```
struct LoginResponse: Decodable {
  // ...
}

struct LoginEndpoint: Endpoint {
   typealias Response = LoginResponse
   let request: URLRequest
}
```

and use it:

```
let login = LoginEndpoint(request: URLRequest(...))
call(endpoint: login)
   .sink ...
```

Comment: This looks pretty slick, I'll give it a whirl!